# google webmaster soft 404 on 301

Tags: http-headers, http-status-code-404, 301-redirect, google-webmaster-tools

I'm looking through google webmaster that my page is generating soft 404 errors (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en)

google says: `We recommend that you always return a 404 (Not found) or a 410 (Gone) response code in response to a request for a non-existing page`

But I've got redirects set up that handle old pages to redirect to the proper new pages using a 301. The website links changed because of a use of a framework, which allows it to be more consistent, but the old pages till have links out there to these.

Should I be worried about this? IS google penalizing the site for this?

(Using IIS 8, Tomcat, CF10, Win)

Comment: 301 and 302 are never the proper error code for a 404.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a URL?